# How to structure a HMT with many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

Users and Services are `has many through` relationship. However, each service has its own unique attributes. Should services be separate models? Or should I create one `service` model with many columns (for each attribute). Performance is a concern.

3 example services:

```
Service 1 requires zipcode:string, phone_number:string
Service 2 requires licensePlate:string, carColor:string
Service 3 requires shoeSize:integer, shoeColor: string
...
Service 100 ...
```

#### Option A (`has_many :through`):

```
rails g model services name:string
Join Model:
rails g model service_user zipcode:string phone_number:string licensePlate:string carColor:string shoeSize:integer shoeColor: string
```

or

#### Option B (separate `One to Many`):

```
rails g model service1 user_id: integer zipcode:string phone_number:string
rails g model service2 user_id: integer licensePlate:string carColor:string
rails g model service3 user_id: integer shoeSize:integer shoeColor: string
```

Comment: What's the join model?

Comment: what is a service? are you sure a generic "service" is the correct model for this? Why are the zipcode/phone number related in some way to the licenseplate/carcolor of your users? Why not a standard one to many relationship with cars, shoes, etc tables

Comment: @RichPeck I realized I left out the join models. I added it to option A. I don't think Option B needs a join model?  It is a One to Many Relation

Comment: @jtmarmon So are you saying I should have separate models for each service? What if there were 100+ services? Is Option B something along the lines of what you described?

Comment: can you explain your domain model? these just seem like user attributes and describing them as services seems weird

Comment: @jtmarmon Basically the user selects which services they want to use. But each service needs some user info that is unique to the service. What's the best way to store these user info?

Answer (score 0):

In regards your options, `Option A` is the only plausible one ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

When given the opportunity, *never* replicate code, models or views. Reuse & refactor - it makes life simpler.

If your services are *that* different (you haven't stated whether they are or not), you'll benefit from looking to [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/); this will save one set of data in the database, allowing you to have multiple models to call. I wouldn't recommend this for you, although you're welcome to try it.

--

I would personally use the following:

```
#app/models/service.rb
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   # id service_type zipcode phone_number license_plate car_color shoe_color

   enum service_type: [:1, :2, :3]

   has_many :user_services
   has_many :users, through: :user_services
end 

#app/models/user_service.rb
class UserService < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :service
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_services
   has_many :services, through: :user_services   
end
```

I would include all your mentioned attributes in a single model. Honestly, there aren't that many. Performance degradation only really happens after you start looking at masses of NULL data. You can always use [`select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) to pull only the attributes you need.

The only thing I *might* do is add custom attributes to the join model. I'd still add separate fields for them all, although I think it would be overkill to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Would this still perform efficiently if there were 100x services each with 2 unique attributes? That would mean the model containing attributes would have over 200 columns. The user might only have 5-10 services, the rest null data.

Comment: Well that's out of scope of the question. You didn't mention the sizes involved :) In that case, why don't you make the `Service` model *only* for service data (name etc), and have extras associated to it through a relation? EG `service has_many :taxi_services, -> { where type: 1}`

Comment: By "extras associated to it" do you mean have multiple models linked to `Service` in a `has_many` relationship as in your example? So `service has_many :taxi_settings` and `service has_many :shoe_settings`

Comment: Yes exactly. But I'd need to see more context to make an update on my answer